# Make VIM act as Notepad++ on mixed line endings

Tags: vim, editors, newlines

I've googled all around and found tons of weird solutions to ^M problem, but couldn't find one and simple: how could I just open any file, like in Notepad++ and work on it? I don't want to mess with LF and CR stuff, anyway git will correct it on push. Is there a "stupid" solution for this issue?
One little thing, I'm forced to work in the World Evil OS right now, so the solution should work for it.

Comment: How does Notepad++ handle mixed line endings?

Answer (score 1):

```
:set binary
```

or

```
$ vim -b file
```

This will leave all line endings as-is, and lines are separated by single `<NL>` characters. I don't recommend using it, but you've explicitly asked for a "stupid solution".

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to fix your line endings.

To convert the file to `\n` line endings:

```
:%s/\r$
```

To convert the file to `\r\n` line endings (untested):

```
:%s/[^\r]\n/\r\n/
```

You can make vim perform one of these operations automatically when you open a file:

```
autocmd BufRead, * normal :%s/\r$
```

You could also use the `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` [utilites](http://www.bastet.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately "fixing" line endings is unrealistic when working in teams with 5 people with different editors constantly editing and contributing new different line endings ...

Answer (score 0):

I use vim on cygwin myself - and if the file is labeled correctly as a dos file, it does not show the ^M characters, and I even have the the info line at the bottom set to tell me if it is a dos or unix type file. Some files may have windows line endings, but still show up as unix - if I run dos2unix on those files it is then fixed, and vim correctly labels it and hides ^M the next time I open that file.